# Duden definitions of "zu"

Tags: standard-german

Duden gives

"kennzeichnet den Ort, die Lage des Sichbefindens, Sichabspielens von etwas"

and

"drückt aus, dass etwas zu etwas anderem hinzukommt, hinzugefügt, -gegeben wird"

as two definitions of "zu."

What are the meanings of "Sichbefindens," "Sichabspielns," "hinzukommt(?)gegeben," and "hinzugefügt(?)gegeben" in this context? How does one interpret the meanings of compound nouns whose meanings may not be readily understandable?

Answer (score 1):

"Sichbefinden" and "Sichabspielen" (of which these are the genetive forms, hence the *-s*) are nominalisations of verbs: "sich befinden" is to be located and "sich abspielen" is to happen. Thus, "der Ort des Sichabspielens" literally means "the place of happening", i.e. the place where something happens.

"hinzukommt", "hinzugegeben" and "hinzugefügt" are all separable verbs, not nouns, and they share the first element *hinzu*, "in addition to". "hinzukommen", "hinzugegeben werden" and "hinzugefügt werden" mean basically the same thing, "to be added".

Comment: Thanks, good answer. How would you interpret this: “das passt nicht zu Bier.” That doesn’t go with beer? That doesn’t pass as beer (ie, that’s not beer)? Something different?

Comment: Also, to be sure, adding the “-gegeben” to the verbs prior does nothing really, right?